# Finding the center of a fusion table geometry

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have a fusion table that has a geometry column.  I'd like to be able to zoom to that particular geometry, but I don't have a lat/long.  Is there any way I can find the center of a geometry?  The alternative would be to hard-code a center in a separate column in the fusion table, but I'd like to be able to do this dynamically.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some examples that use geoxml3 to parse the kml that is stored in FusionTables geometry columns (it is fragments of kml).  Once you do that you can use the google.maps.Map fitBounds method to zoom to that geometry.

- [Zoom to single row geometry from table](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/www_advocacy_ucla_edu_Assembly_MapC.html)
- [Zoom to multiple types/multiple rows of geometry from table](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/indianatrails_com_fusiontables_map.html)

These examples use GViz (the Google visualization library), there may be better ways using the new [Fusion Tables API v1.0](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do, thanks!  I'm doing it for Washington State though :).

Comment: You ever get the "Data may still be loading" message after zooming to the geometry?  The zoom worked fine, but I'm getting that message on all of my map tiles for some reason.

Comment: The most common cause of that (for me) is an error in the query which makes it invalid.  Verify that the query you are using to show the FusionTablesLayer is valid.

Comment: It ended up being invalid fusion table IDs.  Thanks.